# PyDev Cannot Find Module

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, ctypes

I am new to Python and using PyDev 2.71 in Eclipse Juno in Windows for the following example:

```
from ctypes import cdll

msvcrt = cdll.mscvrt
message_string = "test\n"
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s", message_string)
```

However, it is generating the following error:

```
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I added the interpreter in Eclipse prior to creating this PyDev module. What am I missing here?

Comment: This seems like a Python error, not a PyDev one. Have you tried running the script in the command prompt? That should eliminate the PyDev aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I had a typo.

It is cdll.**msvcrt** not cdll.**mscvrt**

It works now.